# Unexpected response from an if statement

Tags: php

I have this code located on `domain.com/tutorial.php`:

```
$consolePass = "abcd";
if ($_POST['passField'] == "password")
{
    echo '<font size="4" color="red"><div align="center"><b>Current password:</b> '.$consolePass.'</div></font><hr />';
}
else echo '<div align="center">
<font size="4" color="red"><b>To view console password, please re-enter your account password.</b></font>
<form type="input" action="tutorial.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="password" name="passField"> 
    <button type="submit">View password</button>
</form></div><hr />';
```

I am using php 5.5's password_verify function and storing the encrypted password hashes in `/passes/username/passHash.txt` (this may not be secure but it's ok, this is just a website for me to learn with).

When I echo `$_POST['passField']` it echos whenever I put in. However, when I try to put in password in passField, it never echos `$consolePass`.

Comment: Where do you define it?

Comment: It's defined above. I'll add it, I forgot to copy it. Sorry.

Comment: How are you defining `$_POST['passField']`?

Comment: From the form (`<input type="password" name="passField">`). If they haven't filled in the form yet it just gives a warning about being undefined (which I'm fine with).

Comment: Technically, your code should work. Can you post the form HTML?

Comment: The form is below the if statement (`else echo (html)`)

Comment: (Unrelated: you should always `{}` all the things. Definitely if you `if` is bracketed, you should also bracket the `else`. Just good practice. Not a solution.)

Comment: try with 3 equal signs like === also r u sure that $_POST is set? check with isset

Comment: @Sean87 If loose comparison doesn't work I doubt strict comparison does :-)

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the `if` statement...